# How to call controller method on service start on Topshelf

Tags: c#, asp.net, topshelf

I am trying to run a method on my controller class when my topshelf service starts and I am now finding how to do it. I search and I couldn't find an answer. Can I call a method of my controller class on service startup directly or I do have to do an HttpClient and call an url on localhost?

Code:

Program.cs:

```
        HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            x.Service<OwinService>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(() => new OwinService());
                s.WhenStarted(service => service.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
            });

            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.StartAutomatically();


            x.SetServiceName("Test Service");
            x.SetDisplayName("Test Service");
            x.SetDescription("Service that Imports / Exports to DB information");
            x.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
            {
                recoveryOption.RestartService(0);
            });

        });
```

OwinService.cs:

```
public class OwinService
{
    private IDisposable _webApp;

    public void Start()
    {
        //_timer.Start();
        _webApp = WebApp.Start<ApiConfiguration>("http://+:9000");

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        //_timer.Stop();
        _webApp.Dispose();
    }

}
```

OutputController.cs

```
public class OutputController : ApiController
{
     public void DoSomething() {};
}
```

I want to call the DoSomething() on startup.

Comment: What's the code for the controller and the service?

Comment: Edited the question to include the code

Comment: Why do you want to call an action method from your own app? That doesn't make much sense. Why not abstract that logic out of your controller into its own class, then you can invoke it from wherever you need?

Comment: @mason Unfortunately someone else made this code on my company and back then they didn't though of that need. So the "DoSomething()" method has dependencies and I am not able to migrate all the code. Thats why I am searching for alternatives :/

Comment: So? Identify those dependencies and wire them up when you call the abstracted logic.